# jQuery conflicts in wordpress

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmbytplayer/
But the background video stops and freezes when I run the following jQuery to animate a box from the header. Does anyone know why?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('#open').click(function(){
        jQuery('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-25px'},1000);
        jQuery('#open').fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });
    jQuery('#close').click(function(){
        jQuery('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-800px'},1000);
        jQuery('#open').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: The idea of passing `$` into your function is that you *don't* have to use the verbose `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another tip would be instead of using #open twice, you could use this to reference the same object. Meaning:

$('#open').click(function(){

```
    $('#pull_down_content').animate({'top':'-25px'},1000);
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0);
```

});